# JQuery > Caret/Cursor does not blink when I return focus to a text box using on blur

Tags: jquery, textbox, cursor, focus, onblur

I have a textbox that must accept only numbers. I validate what is entered into the textbox using the JQuery onblur method. If validation fails then I give an Alert Pop Up to tell the user there was a problem and then I programatically return focus to the textbox.

My problem is that when I return focus to the textbox the cursor/caret thing does not blink. It is there and I can type into the textbox without having to click on it first to select it. However the cursor does not blink until I actually click on the textbox. I notice the cursor DOES blink if I don't use the Alert Pop Up.

I set up a small html page to illustrate.. http://jsfiddle.net/xB8Hy/2/ Here is the code...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Plugins/jquery.js"></script>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on("blur","#qty_text", function() {
        var myregexp = /^[0]$|^[1-9][0-9]*$/;
            if( myregexp.test( $("#qty_text").val()) ){
                alert("Input Valid");
            }else{
                setTimeout(function(){
                    alert("Not a valid number");
                    $( "#qty_text" ).focus();
                }, 10);   
            }
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="qty_text">
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas how I can have the pop up but still get the blinking cursor in the text box after the user OKs out of the Alert Pop Up? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well in case anyone cares I ended up using a jQuery modal dialog plugin called SimpleModal. See here: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal_v12/

When you click away from the text box and the validation test fails then the dialog opens and after a few seconds it closes by itself leaving the caret (cursor, whatever you call it) visibly blinking IN the text box. Success.

A little code snippet:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("blur","#qty_text", function() {
       var myregexp = /^[0]$|^[1-9][0-9]*$/;
        if( myregexp.test( $("#qty_text").val()) ){
            alert("Input Valid");
        }else{
            $('#simple-modal').modal({
                onOpen: function (dialog) {
                // If you use the onOpen callback, you must "show"
                // the overlay, data and container elements manually                    
                    dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow');
                    dialog.container.fadeIn('slow');
                    dialog.data.fadeIn('slow');
                },
                onShow: function (dialog) {
                // Close the dialog automatically three seconds after it opens
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        dialog.data.hide();
                        dialog.container.hide();
                        dialog.overlay.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                            $.modal.close(); // must call this!
                            $( "#qty_text" ).focus();
                        });
                    }, 3000);
                }
          });
        }
    }); //<-- end of $(document).on("blur",..)
}); //<-- end of $(document).ready()
</script>
```

And here is the body with the DIV which formats the Dialog box:

```
<body>
<input type="text" id="qty_text">

<!-- The SimpleModal Dialog -->
    <div class="simple-modal" id="simple-modal">
       <div class="simple-modal-header">
         <h1>Quantity Error</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="simple-modal-body">
         <div class="contents">
           <p>Quantity Entered is not a Number</p>
           <p>Please Try Again</p>
         </div>
       </div>
      <div class="simple-modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I don't know why it is that you don't get a blinking caret in the text box after you return focus to it once the OK button on a Javascript Alert Pop Up is clicked. I'd still appreciate if someone could explain that to me.

Comment: I'm having the same problem after trying to programatically return focus to the textbox (or in my case, textarea).  It works as expected on the first try but not thereafter.  Since I'm not using a dialog, SimpleModal wouldn't help.